# Make Flash movie autoload

Tags: flash, animation, embed, autoload

I would like to embed a flash movie on my page but I would need it to autoload from the begining, not only when I reach it through page. I mean, I have a long page and the flash is about in the middle. It plays an animation with sound and I would like it to start itself, not only when I scroll down to it. Is this possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash movies begin playing immediately on loading in the browser (by default). Just make sure your `<object> / <embed>` tags don't have the **play** attribute set to **false** and that your Flash movie doesn't have a `stop()` on frame1 or something preventing it from playing...

Comment: right, but you can check the parameters on the object/embed tags and see if the 'play' attribute is false or not. anyway, you should create a test page and embed the SWF in order to troubleshoot (i.e. is it a problem with the SWF file or the way it's embedded?)

Answer (score 0):

I have had some cases where the movie won't seem to consistently auto play.  I threw together this quick javascript funciton which I call onload to make sure the movie is running:

```
function LoadMovie(){
var movie = document.getElementById('flash_nav');
if(typeof movie.PercentLoaded() == "function")  //not every browser supports this so check first
 {
if(movie.PercentLoaded() < 100)
    {
        movie.LoadMovie(0, movie.data);    
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is supposed to be an ad for some website...I can't change the code on someone else's website...The owner won't accept this method...